# Scrolling down and updating a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want to update my `ListView` when I scroll my `ListView` down (on the last Item )

```
mConnectionList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            private int mLastFirstVisibleItem;
            private boolean isScrollingDown = false;
            private int mLastVisibleItem;

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

                Log.e("lastInScreen", "lastInScreen " + lastInScreen);
                if (mLastFirstVisibleItem <= firstVisibleItem) {
                    Log.i("SCROLLING DOWN", "TRUE");
                    isScrollingDown = false;
                }else{
                    isScrollingDown = true;
                }
                if (mLastFirstVisibleItem > firstVisibleItem) {
                    Log.i("SCROLLING DOWN", "FALSE");
                    isScrollingDown = true;
                }
                mLastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
                mLastVisibleItem = lastInScreen;

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                int sizeList = connectionList.size();
                Log.e("lastVisible", " last " + mLastVisibleItem + " " + isScrollingDown);
                if (!isScrollingDown && mLastVisibleItem == sizeList) {
                    getConnections();
                }

            }
        });
```

This cause update my `ListView` then I scroll down on my listView but when I scroll up (when is on the end of listView ) my `ListView` is updating

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom component:

```
public class EndlessListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener {
  ..
  @Override
  public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
     ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
}
```

and in onScroll you can implement your update logic:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

   if (getAdapter() == null)
     return ;

   if (getAdapter().getCount() == 0)
    return ;

  int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;
  if (l <= totalItemCount && !isLoading) {
     // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
     this.addFooterView(footer);
     isLoading = true;
     listener.loadData();
  }
}
```

You could customize the ListView footer to notify the updating process:

```
public void setLoadingView(int resId) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) super.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
footer = (View) inflater.inflate(resId, null);
this.addFooterView(footer);
}
```

Hope this will help you.
You can find all the source code in my [blog post](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-listview-endless-adapter-2.html)

Comment: Thank you I would check this